# DataGridView поиск через textbox. С использованием BindingSource

Tags: c#, поиск, datagridview, search, bindingsource

Решил попробовать поиск по DataGridView, в котором данные хранятся в bindingsource

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для поиска использую textbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter 
= string.Format("ProjectName LIKE '{0}%' OR ProjectName LIKE '% {0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

Однако получаю ошибки сразу после ввода первого же символа.
Если это поместить в блок try-catch, то следующая ошибка.

Как можно правильно реализовать данный поиск?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Подключение к бд хранится в Settings.settings

Comment: (Искать) выборку  нужно  делать с помощью `BindingSource.Filter`, кстати то что вы хотите сделать называется не поиском, а фильтрацией или выборкой, о чем прозрачно намекает само название свойства.

Comment: А Вы бы не могли подсказать работоспособный поиск?

Comment: Ну, вы попробуйте сделать тот же `"ProjectName LIKE '{0}%' OR ProjectName LIKE '% {0}%'"` у BindingSource сделать и посмотрите работает или нет.

Comment: Никогда с bindingsource особо не работал. Документацию почитал. Но всё равно смутно представляю сам синтаксис написания:(

Comment: Вот в документации [пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Cannot find table 0

Comment: BindingSource не хранит никакие данные. Он лишь является посредником между настоящим источником и компонентом. Что у вас привязано к BindingSource: DataTable, List<T> или какая-то другая коллекция?

Comment: Где у вас или в примере? Вы все-таки думайте о том, что мне то ваш код не виден.

Comment: DataTable pt = new DataTable();
pt = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;
DataView dv1 = new DataView(pt);
dv1.RowFilter = " ProjectName LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
dataGridView2.DataSource = dv1;
Пробовал так. Толку нет. Не имею представления, какова правильная работа этих компонентов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Пример работы]

Работаем через BindingSource так

```
public partial class FormView : Form
{
    //работа с БД
    private readonly IDataContext _dataContext = new TestDataContext();
    //источник привязки для DGV
    private readonly BindingSource _bsPeople = new BindingSource();
    //объект формирования выборок для DGV
    private readonly FilterDgv _filterDgv = new FilterDgv();

    public FormView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //привязки
        SetBindings();
        //загрузка Людей
        LoadData();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример фильтрации в DGV";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Установка привязок
    /// </summary>
    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //DGV
        _bsPeople.DataSource = typeof(List<Person>);
        _dataGridViewPeople.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _dataGridViewPeople.DataSource = _bsPeople;

        //текстбоксы для выборки
        var bFN = new Binding("Text", _filterDgv, nameof(FilterDgv.FirstName));
        bFN.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        _textBoxFindFirstName.DataBindings
                             .Add(bFN);

        var bLN = new Binding("Text", _filterDgv, nameof(FilterDgv.LastName));
        bLN.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        _textBoxFindLastName.DataBindings
                            .Add(bLN);

        var bAg = new Binding("Text", _filterDgv, nameof(FilterDgv.Age));
        bAg.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        _textBoxFindAge.DataBindings
                       .Add(bAg);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка данных в DGV
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadData()
    {
        DataSet data = _dataContext.GetPeople();
        _bsPeople.DataSource = data.Tables[0];

        //подписка на событие изменение свойств у фильтрующего объекта
        _filterDgv.PropertyChanged += _filterDgv_PropertyChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработчик события изменения свойств у фильтрующего объекта
    /// Формирование и применения фильтра к DGV через BindingSource
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void _filterDgv_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var filters = new List<string>();

        //организуем список условий
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_filterDgv.FirstName))
        {
            filters.Add($"{nameof(Person.FirstName)} LIKE '{_filterDgv.FirstName}%'");
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_filterDgv.LastName))
        {
            filters.Add($"{nameof(Person.LastName)} LIKE '{_filterDgv.LastName}%'");
        }
        if (_filterDgv.Age > 0)
        {
            filters.Add($"{nameof(Person.Age)} > {_filterDgv.Age}");
        }

        //удаляем предыдущий фильтр
        _bsPeople.RemoveFilter();

        //назначаем фильтрацию
        if (filters.Count == 1)
        {
            _bsPeople.Filter = filters.First();
        }
        else if (filters.Count > 1)
        {
            _bsPeople.Filter = String.Join(" AND ", filters);
        }
        else
        { }
    }
}
```

Весь код примера [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/FilterDGV)